# Creating jquery plugin for objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I want to create a jquery plugin for array splice(opposite of `push()` function).But I get error

`Uncaught TypeError: allfiles.pull is not a function`
Here is my code:

```js
$.fn.pull = function (index) {
 this.splice(index-1,1);
}

var allfiles = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$("div").html(allfiles);
allfiles.pull(1);
$("div").html(allfiles);
```

```css
.first:before{
content:'Before:';
}
.second:before{
content:'After:';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: Why would a jQuery plugin work on a regular array? jQuery plugins work on jQuery collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `$.fn.pull` extends the jQuery function list, it does not add a method to the object `Array`. To do that do `Array.prototype.pull`. In your original code `Array.pull` (`allfiles.pull`) is `undefined`, because you've never declared it.

I've changed your code and wrapped the array into a jQuery function: `$(allfiles)`. This should give you what you need.

```js
$.fn.pull = function (index) {
 this.splice(index-1,1);
  return this.toArray();
}

var allfiles = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$("div.first").html(allfiles);
allfiles = $(allfiles).pull(1);
$("div.second").html(allfiles);
```

```css
.first:before{
content:'Before:';
}
.second:before{
content:'After:';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Stack Snippet with Array.prototype.pull (NOT RECOMMENDED*)

```js
Array.prototype.pull = function (index) {
 return this.splice(index-1,1);
}

var allfiles = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
$("div.first").html(allfiles);
allfiles.pull(1);
$("div.second").html(allfiles);
```

```css
.first:before{
content:'Before:';
}
.second:before{
content:'After:';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

> * Altering the original object of JavaScript such as `Array` with custom functions is not recommended. Behaviour can change or external scripts like jQuery could rely on the same names. `pull` is pretty generic. At least use a destinctive name `myproject_pull`.

Comment: Thank u. I used `Array.prototype.pull` and it worked.

Comment: If the answer worked, please upvote and check answered.